# datetime.datetime has no attribute "datetime"

Tags: python, import, python-datetime

I'm trying to determine if the current time is before or after a specified date using this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def presidentvoting(self):
    electiondate = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31, 0, 0)
    current_time = datetime.now()
    if current_time > electiondate:
        print("You can no longer vote")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
electiondate = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31, 0, 0)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: datetime.datetime has no attribute...? Which one?

Comment: Could you copy the traceback of the error as well as how you imported the datetime module?

Comment: I suspect you used `from datetime import datetime`?

Comment: yes I used import datetime and from datetime import datetime

Comment: and this is the error(electiondate = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 31, 0, 0)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime` is a module which contains a function<sup>1</sup> that is also called `datetime`.

You can use it like this:

```
import datetime
#      ^^^^^^^^
#      the module

x = datetime.datetime(...)
#            ^^^^^^^^ the function
#   ^^^^^^^^ the module
```

Here `datetime` refers to the module, and `datetime.datetime` refers to the function in the module.

Or you can only import the function from the module, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
#    ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^
#    the module      the function

x = datetime(...)
#   ^^^^^^^^ the function
```

You used a mixture of those two, which does not work:

```
from datetime import datetime
#    ^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^
#    the module      the function

x = datetime.datetime(...)
#            ^^^^^^^^ this does not exist
#   ^^^^^^^^ the function
```

---

In case use used

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
```

then after the first line, `datetime` would refer to the module (which on its own would have been correct), but the second line would overwrite that and `datetime` would no longer refer to the module, but to the function.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, `datetime.datetime` is a class, not a function, but for the purpose of this answer it does not matter.